# How to use PyVISA on Ubuntu to interact with a vector network analyzer?

Tags: pyvisa

Using **PyVISA** on an Ubuntu-operating computer (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS), I would like to interact with a VNA machine (**E8361A**, Agilent technologies) in the following way,

**1-** Connect to the VNA through a port.

**2-** Send a signal to VNA to start S-parameter measurements within a specified frequency range at specified number of points.

**3-** Send a signal to VNA to stop S-parameter measurement, fetch the S-parameter data, transfer the data to the PC and save the data.

**Q1:** Which VNA port do you recommend to use (GPIB, Ethernet or USB), and why?
**Q2:** Depending on the VNA port, what hardware is required to connect the PC to the VNA?
**Q3:** Is there a way to adjust the power level of the VNA stimulus signal? If yes, how to inquire the maximum and minimum power levels? Can the power level be adjusted continuously or only discrete power levels are avilable? (Basically, how to control VNA's internal amplifiers/attenuators?
**Q4:** Can you please share a sample Python code which uses PyVISA to save S-paramater data in the fashion described in steps 1--3?
**Q5:** Does trigger port have to do anything with sending signals to the VNA to start and stop measurements?

Comment: This is not a programming-related question, which makes it off-topic here. Also, even if your question was related to programming, this is a question and answer site. Note that **question** is singular, not plural. It's not a *numbered list of questions* site. You should go back and review the [help] pages to better understand the site and how it works - it will greatly improve your experiences here.

Comment: The end goal is to communicate with a VNA machine using a Python code. The itemized questions describe different aspects of the main question in the title to be talked about. They give a picture of my current understanding to the experts, which would help me to be corrected by them.

Formally, you are correct. But, I care more about solving the problem.

Comment: But 4 of your 5 questions are not about programming, which makes them off-topic, and the one that mentions Python is not a specific programming question. Read my first comment again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not working on ubuntu, nor I have the machine you have I can't say much. I am also rather new to pyVISA so my knowledge there is also limited, but since no one else answered:

Q1. I use a usb port since it is the only one I have, but the faster the better i would assume. There seems to me to be more GPIB examples found on the internet so maybe it is an easier starting point.

Q2. As with others (like mine) I would assume only a cable.

Q3. Yes, see the [write][1] function. It may look something like this:

```
# Connect PNA to computer using resource_manager etc., it is well documented
PNA.Write(f':SOUR{channel_num}:POW:LEV:IMM:AMPL {source_level},"{source_name}"')
```

For the maximum and minimum values see the documentation of your hardware.

Q4. Your 'Send a signal' I don't know how to do. But you could just while-loop and send-and-recieve in each instance until you want it to stop. Here is an example from keysight:
https://edadocs.software.keysight.com/kkbopen/a-python-programming-example-for-the-pna-family-vnas-sweep-time-various-point-counts-no-error-correction-577935568.html

Q5. I don't know.

EDIT: On Q4: I found this [link][2] , which would what I believe result in

```
PNA.write('SENS:SWE:MODE CONT') for continous sweeping and 
PNA.write('SENS:SWE:MODE SING') for single sweeping.
```

In this case change from CONT to SING when appropriate and it should stop sweeping.
[1]: https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pyvisa/resources/messagebased.html#MessageBasedResource.write
[2]: https://rfmw.em.keysight.com/wireless/helpfiles/89600b/webhelp/Subsystems/gui/content/mnu_control_sweep.htm